# Want to know how to create a arrow by the side of tab

Tags: bootstrap-4

Herewith I have attached a photo There is small arrow on the side , I want know How to create it, for better clarification I have attached a screen shot, Kindly help me out 
Ps: I'm a beginner .
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zghw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ::after (:after) to create the triangles / arrows.

> ::after creates a pseudo-element that is the last child of the
>   selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an
>   element with the content property. It is inline by default. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

And set its size and border-width. You can use any combination but then rotate the triangle accordingly. For more info, visit [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/)

---

Use CSS `nth-child` to set  background of the odd and even triangles.

> The :nth-child() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their
>   position in a group of siblings. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```css
/* create the triangle for the sections except the last one */

.bg-silver {
   background-color: #e9e9e9 !important;
 }

.el-left-arrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: -27px;
  top: calc((100% - 15px) / 2);
  z-index: 1000000;
}


/* Set background of the active section's triangle  */

.el-active:after {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #009975 !important;
  ;
}


/* Set background of the odd section's triangle */

.el-left-arrow:nth-child(odd):after {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #ffffff;
}


/* Set background of the even section's triangle */

.el-left-arrow:nth-child(even):after {
  border-bottom: 20px solid #e9e9e9;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="d-flex flex-wrap  ">
  <div class="py-1 px-5 bg-success position-relative el-left-arrow el-active">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
      <h1>7</h1>
      <p class="mb-0">New Load</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="py-1 px-4 bg-silver  position-relative el-left-arrow">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
      <h1>0</h1>
      <p class="mb-0">Contact In Future</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="py-1 px-4 position-relative  el-left-arrow">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
      <h1>0</h1>
      <p class="mb-0">Follow up</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="py-1 px-4 bg-silver position-relative el-left-arrow">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
      <h1>0</h1>
      <p class="mb-0">Responded</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="py-1 px-4 position-relative el-left-arrow">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
      <h1>0</h1>
      <p class="mb-0">Favourite</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="py-1 px-4 bg-silver position-relative el-left-arrow">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
      <h1>0</h1>
      <p class="mb-0">Converted</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="py-1 px-4  position-relative">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column text-center">
      <h1>0</h1>
      <p class="mb-0">All</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you So much for the help,I will try it .